# Transpose / Dynamic PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-loop, pivot

[image]

into the following:

[image]

Credit is limited with 6. Blank spots can be null. I want to create new columns named as Credit1,Credit2, .. ,Credit6. Can I use `PIVOT` for this scenario? Or any other simple way to transpose the table?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The answer will probably be product specific.) And note that most people here want formatted text instead of images.

Comment: DB is SQL Server. Sorry for the format i used

Comment: Is it always 6 credits  ?

Comment: How to order the credits ? Do you have any other column to find the order ?

Comment: There is no other column to find order. It is always 6 credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL version:

```
CREATE TABLE  #SampleData 
(
   Name varchar(50),
   Credits int
)

INSERT INTO #SampleData
VALUES ('John', 10),('John', 20),
('Bath', 90), ('Bath', 60), ('Bath', 70),('Bath', 80),('Bath', 50),
('Richard', 75)

DECLARE @ColPivot nvarchar(max)
;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT * , 'Credit' + CAST(row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.Name ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS varchar(5)) AS CreditGroup
   FROM #SampleData sd
)
SELECT @ColPivot = STUFF(
                    (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + t.CreditGroup FROM temp t FOR XML PATH (''))
                   ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 
      N';WITH temp AS
        (
            SELECT * , ''Credit'' + CAST(row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.Name ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS varchar(5)) AS CreditGroup
            FROM #SampleData sd
        )
         Select [Name],  ' + @ColPivot + 
        ' FROM 
         (
            SELECT [Name], Credits, CreditGroup FROM temp 
         ) src
         PIVOT
         (
            MAX(Credits) FOR CreditGroup IN ('+ @ColPivot+ ')
         )pvt
        '
PRINT @query

EXEC (@query)

DROP TABLE #SampleData
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/HKKX40372)

Comment: am too lazy to write dynamic version +1